# Can DAO's hold state information

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

May be this might sound a bit mundane, can someone tell me if there is any good practise which says DAO's should not store state information i.e. non static non final member variables? Most of the DAO's that i have come accross mainly contain only static and final variables.

```
public class CustomerDAO extends CommonDAO{

private String txnid;
private String txnName;

getters....setters..
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, a DAO is "just a pipe", made to encapsulate database communication. It constructs and executes the queries or/and proxies the `EntityManager`, so at least for JPA, no state is needed, except for the `EntityManager` instance. Queries do not depend on each other directly.

So I would put the question the other way round - What sensible state could a DAO have?

Comment: Where i am coming from is, I have a very specific scenario where in order to provide the input parameters to a query requires changes to multiple DAO methods which at this moment i am trying to avoid. So i was just wondering if i can keep this inputs in a ThreadLocal variable but was not aware of what the best practises say. I know this sounds like a bad design have to think through.

Comment: @hakish - this sounds like the DAO is using the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create queries, like the `EntityManager` does. In order to maintain a clear separation of concerns I would extract the stateful query building part into it's own stateful class, then pass the result to the DAO, or refactor the DAO to be stateless by creating methods that require the complete data needed for query creation. If this results in too many method parameters, they can be encapsulated in a new type like `Predicates` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly no on this one: DAOs' whole reason for existing is to provide a stateless range of DB access methods.  Most developers reading your code would be very surprised to find any state.

Also, state as you are illustrating is not thread safe - you could get into a right mess doing that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

DAOs are usually implemented following the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) - meaning there is only one instance of the DAO for every single entity, so state information would be shared among all parts of the application using the DAO